# Sqoop installation export and import from postgresql

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, sqoop

I v'e just installed sqoop and was testing it . I tried to export some data from hdfs to postgresql using sqoop. When I run it it throws the following exception : `java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check task tracker logs` . I think there may also have been a problem in installation.

The File content is :

```
ustNU 45
MB1bA 0
gNbCO 76
iZP10 39
B2aoo 45
SI7eG 93
5sC4k 60
2IhFV 2
u2A48 16
yvy6R 51
LNhsV 26
mZ2yn 65
80Gp3 43
Wk5Ag 85
VUfyp 93
P077j 94
f1Oj5 11
LxJkg 72
0H7NP 99
Dk406 25
g4KRp 76
Fw3U0 80
6LD59 1
07KHx 91
F1S88 72
Bnb0v 85
A2qM7 79
Z6cAt 81
0M3DO 23
m0s09 44
KIvwd 13
GNUD0 78
um93a 20
19bHv 75
4Of3s 75
5hFen 16
```

This is the posgres table:

```
    Table "public.mysort"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 name   | text    | 
 marks  | integer |
```

The sqoop command is:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:postgresql://localhost/testdb --username akshay --password akshay --table mysort -m 1 --export-dir MySort/input
```

Followed by the error:

```
Warning: /usr/lib/hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
14/06/11 18:28:06 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
14/06/11 18:28:06 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
14/06/11 18:28:06 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
14/06/11 18:28:06 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM "mysort" AS t LIMIT 1
14/06/11 18:28:06 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/local/hadoop
Note: /tmp/sqoop-hduser/compile/0402ad4b5cf7980040264af35de406cb/mysort.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
14/06/11 18:28:07 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-hduser/compile/0402ad4b5cf7980040264af35de406cb/mysort.jar
14/06/11 18:28:07 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Beginning export of mysort
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
14/06/11 18:28:22 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/06/11 18:28:22 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
14/06/11 18:28:23 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.speculative
14/06/11 18:28:23 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.speculative
14/06/11 18:28:23 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
14/06/11 18:28:23 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
14/06/11 18:28:24 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/06/11 18:28:24 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/06/11 18:28:25 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
14/06/11 18:28:25 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1402488523460_0003
14/06/11 18:28:25 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1402488523460_0003
14/06/11 18:28:25 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1402488523460_0003/
14/06/11 18:28:25 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1402488523460_0003
14/06/11 18:28:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1402488523460_0003 running in uber mode : false
14/06/11 18:28:46 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/06/11 18:29:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1402488523460_0003_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check task tracker logs
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:839)
    at mysort.__loadFromFields(mysort.java:198)
    at mysort.parse(mysort.java:147)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:83)
    ... 10 more

14/06/11 18:29:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1402488523460_0003_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check task tracker logs
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:839)
    at mysort.__loadFromFields(mysort.java:198)
    at mysort.parse(mysort.java:147)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:83)
    ... 10 more

14/06/11 18:29:42 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1402488523460_0003_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check task tracker logs
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:839)
    at mysort.__loadFromFields(mysort.java:198)
    at mysort.parse(mysort.java:147)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:83)
    ... 10 more

14/06/11 18:30:03 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
14/06/11 18:30:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1402488523460_0003 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1402488523460_0003_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

14/06/11 18:30:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 9
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=4
        Launched map tasks=4
        Other local map tasks=3
        Data-local map tasks=1
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=69336
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=69336
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=69336
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=71000064
14/06/11 18:30:03 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
14/06/11 18:30:03 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 100.1476 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
14/06/11 18:30:03 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
14/06/11 18:30:03 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Exported 0 records.
14/06/11 18:30:03 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Error during export: Export job failed!
```

This is the log file :

```
2014-06-11 17:54:37,601 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
2014-06-11 17:54:37,602 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
2014-06-11 17:54:52,678 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2014-06-11 17:54:52,777 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2014-06-11 17:54:52,846 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2014-06-11 17:54:52,847 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MapTask metrics system started
2014-06-11 17:54:52,855 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Executing with tokens:
2014-06-11 17:54:52,855 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Kind: mapreduce.job, Service: job_1402488523460_0002, Ident: (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.token.JobTokenIdentifier@971d0d8)
2014-06-11 17:54:52,901 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Sleeping for 0ms before retrying again. Got null now.
2014-06-11 17:54:53,165 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: mapreduce.cluster.local.dir for child: /tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1402488523460_0002
2014-06-11 17:54:53,249 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
2014-06-11 17:54:53,249 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
2014-06-11 17:54:53,393 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2014-06-11 17:54:53,689 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
2014-06-11 17:54:53,899 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Processing split: Paths:/user/hduser/MySort/input/data.txt:0+891082
2014-06-11 17:54:53,904 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: map.input.file is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.input.file
2014-06-11 17:54:53,904 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: map.input.start is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.input.start
2014-06-11 17:54:53,904 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: map.input.length is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.input.length
2014-06-11 17:54:54,028 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: 
2014-06-11 17:54:54,028 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: Exception raised during data export
2014-06-11 17:54:54,028 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: 
2014-06-11 17:54:54,028 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: Exception: 
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:839)
    at mysort.__loadFromFields(mysort.java:198)
    at mysort.parse(mysort.java:147)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:83)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
2014-06-11 17:54:54,030 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: On input: ustNU 45
2014-06-11 17:54:54,031 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: On input file: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hduser/MySort/input/data.txt
2014-06-11 17:54:54,031 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: At position 0
2014-06-11 17:54:54,031 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: 
2014-06-11 17:54:54,031 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: Currently processing split:
2014-06-11 17:54:54,031 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: Paths:/user/hduser/MySort/input/data.txt:0+891082
2014-06-11 17:54:54,031 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: 
2014-06-11 17:54:54,031 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: This issue might not necessarily be caused by current input
2014-06-11 17:54:54,031 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: due to the batching nature of export.
2014-06-11 17:54:54,031 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: 
2014-06-11 17:54:54,032 INFO [Thread-12] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper: Auto-progress thread is finished. keepGoing=false
2014-06-11 17:54:54,033 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hduser (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check task tracker logs
2014-06-11 17:54:54,033 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Exception running child : java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check task tracker logs
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:839)
    at mysort.__loadFromFields(mysort.java:198)
    at mysort.parse(mysort.java:147)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:83)
    ... 10 more

2014-06-11 17:54:54,037 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Runnning cleanup for the task
```

Any help in resolving the issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the complete procedure for installation and import and export commands for Sqoop. Hope fully it may be helpful to some one. This one is tried and tested by me and actually works.**

```
Download : apache.mirrors.tds.net/sqoop/1.4.4/sqoop-1.4.4.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha.tar.gz

sudo mv sqoop-1.4.4.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha.tar.gz /usr/lib/sqoop

copy paste followingtwo lines in .bashrc
export SQOOP_HOME=/usr/lib/sqoop
export PATH=$PATH:$SQOOP_HOME/bin

Go to /usr/lib/sqoop/conf folder and copy sqoop-env-template.sh to new file sqoop-env.sh and modify export HADOOP_HOME ,HBASE_HOME,etc to the installation directory

Download the postgresql conector jar file from jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc41.jar

create a directory manager.d in sqoop/conf/

create a file postgresql in conf/  and add the following line in it
org.postgresql.Driver=/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc41.jar

name the connector.jar file accordingly
```

For Export

```
Create a user in postgres:
createuser -P -s -e ace
Enter password for new role: ace
Enter it again: ace


CREATE DATABASE testdb OWNER ace TABLESPACE ace;

create table stud1(id int,name text);

Create a file student.txt
Add lines such as:
1,Ace
2,iloveapis

hadoop fs -put student.txt 

sqoop export --connect jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb --username ace --password ace --table stud1 -m 1 --export-dir student.txt

check in postgres: Select * from stud1;
```

For Import:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb --username akshay --password akshay --table stud1 --m 1

hadoop fs -ls -R stud1
```

Expected Output:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup          0 2014-06-13 18:10 stud1/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup         21 2014-06-13 18:10 stud1/part-m-00000


hadoop fs -cat stud1/part-m-00000
```

Expected Output:

```
1,Ace
2,iloveapis


hadoop fs -copyToLocal stud1/part-m-00000 $HOME/imported_data.txt
```